# Empty dynamic link assetlinks.json issue when using firebase hosting

Tags: android, firebase, jekyll, firebase-hosting, twa

The response of https://evrcare.co/.well-known/assetlinks.json is coming [] instead of valid json.
I've put the correct `assetlinks.json` file inside `.well-known` folder.
  What happens now is that my TWA shows a url bar (which is not supposed to if response of  https://evrcare.co/.well-known/assetlinks.json is correct json).
However, I can see complete json if I put `assetlinks.json` in some other folder than `.well-known` like : https://evrcare.co/well-known/assetlinks.json

So I looked over the internet and they suggested couple of ways, none of them worked.
like:

1) Create another folder  `well-known` and put `assetlinks.json` and then redirect:

firebase.json:

```
 {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "destination": "/well-known/assetlinks.json"
      }
```

Didn't work. response: []

2) add header as `application/json` for `**/.well-known/**`

firebase.json:

```
 "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-store"
          },
          {
            "key": "Expires",
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "key": "Pragma",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/.well-known/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Didn't work. response []

3) add `"appAssociation": "NONE"` to firebase.json.

Didn't work. I get page not found.

4) add "dynamicLinks": true to "rewrites"

firebase.json:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/**",
    "dynamicLinks": true
  }
],
```

Didn't work. response: []

---

You can test https://evrcare.co/.well-known/assetlinks.json and https://evrcare.co/well-known/assetlinks.json with my current `firebase.json` config:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "_site",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/bigben",
        "function": "bigben"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },

      {
        "source": "/.well-known/assetlinks.json",
        "destination": "/well-known/assetlinks.json"
      }
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-store"
          },
          {
            "key": "Expires",
            "value": "0"
          },
          {
            "key": "Pragma",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/.well-known/**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    }
  }
}
```

I followed https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/ to create TWA and assetlinks.json file.

**firebase-tools:**  8.0.2

**Platform:** Windows

---

Example of a valid JSON: https://google.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Tools to verify linking:

- https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator
- https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://evrcare.co&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dumb. My build tool (jekyll) was ignoring folders which start with dot.

Had to add this to my `_config.yml` to make it work:

```
# Folders with dotfiles are ignored by default.
include: [.well-known]
```